# No sync between Pidgin and Hangouts notifications

Tags: sync, notifications, pidgin, google-hangouts

I use Hangouts app on my Android device and Pidgin on my Windows PC. Until a few months ago, the notifications synchronized perfectly between the two applications. For instance, when I am actively using the Pidgin client to chat with a Hangouts contact, I don't get notifications on the Hangouts app. If someone pings me and I haven't responded for a certain period of time on Pidgin, I get the notification on Hangouts app. All good.

But recently, the notification synchronization is completely gone. Here I am actively using Pidgin for chatting and I keep getting annoying notifications on Hangouts for the same chat session. I cannot turn off Hangouts notifications, because then when I am on the go, I don't receive any notifications.

How can this be fixed? Has Google changed their API in a way that Pidgin can no longer "tell" Hangouts that "the user is with me right now, you keep quiet" ?

Comment: This was a feature of pidgin? You might want to [submit a bug report](https://pidgin.im/support/) or look through the support tickets.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the existing bugs and looks like this issue was reported and closed as 'cantfix'. https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/16748. Oh well.

Comment: maybe try reverting back to a older version?